# PHPExcel mapping inside a while a loop

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to map my PHPExcel based on the picture **below**. 
[image]

When I started to map my data that I got from the database I got only the customers information. However, I still want to get the **Items** that the customer ordered and map it in my PHPExcel.

Here's what I've done so far. 
[image]

Here's my code:

```
 $sqlmanagement = "select `check`, concat(hour, ':', minute) as `time`, 
 customer, unit, amount, employee, manager from gndtndr  where type = 3 and 
 typeid = 1  and STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' 
 order by STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%m/%d/%Y')";


 $connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) 

  or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . 
 mysql_errno()); 
 //select database 
 $Db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect) 
 or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . 
 mysql_errno()); 
//execute query 
 $resultmanagement = @mysql_query($sqlmanagement,$connect) 
 or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . 
 mysql_errno()); 

      $rowManagementDiscresult = 2;

  while($rowmanagement = mysql_fetch_array($resultmanagement)){  

  $rowmanagement1 = $rowManagementDiscresult + 1;

  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowManagementDiscresult, 
  $rowmanagement['check']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowManagementDiscresult, 
  $rowmanagement['time']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowManagementDiscresult, 
  $rowmanagement['customer']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowManagementDiscresult, 
  $rowmanagement['unit']);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowManagementDiscresult, 
  '1');
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowManagementDiscresult, 
  $rowmanagement['amount']);




  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowmanagement1, 'ITEMS 
  HERE');



  $rowManagementDiscresult++;
  }
```

Comment: if your code has mysql_connect(), mysql_query() and other mysql_* functions, they will not work anymore in the latest version of PHP 7.

MySQL extension (ext/mysql) with all mysql_* functions has been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. You must use Mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php#book.mysqli

Comment: My PHP version is 5.6 :c 
will this not work either?